# To prove given $ r \cdot f_1+f_2\cdot (s+1)$ one who knows $f_2$ cannot find out what $f_1$ is

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-distributions, polynomials, ring-theory

We define the polynomials $r,f_1,f_2,s\in R[x]$. Where $r$ is a random degree 1 polynomial and $s$ is a random polynomial such that: $\deg(s)=\deg(f_1)=\deg(f_2)$. Let $R$ be $\mathbb {Z}_q$ where $q$ is a large prime number

My question: how to To prove "Given $r\cdot f_1+f_2 \cdot (s+1)$ one who knows only $f_2$ cannot learn anything about $f_1$."?

Thanks.

Comment: Who is $R$? a generic ring or the field of reals??

Comment: So this person, does he know the full polynomial $rf_1+f_2(s+1)$ and $f_2$ itself and nothing more?

Comment: Let $R$ be $\mathbb {Z}_q$ where $q$ is a large prime number.

Comment: @Arthur Yes. That's right.

Comment: I do know that if $r$ is a random polynomial of the same as the degree of the other polynomials (e.g. $f_1$) then he cannot find out. But I do not know whether the same is true for degree one $r$. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~leak/papers/set-tech-full.pdf